# Convert Specific Date Time

Tags: c#, converters

I want to add two dates,
for example
17 days and 01 hours and 40 minutes + 02 days and 03 hours and 40 minutes
but each day is only 07 hours and 20 minutes and not 24 hours.
I wrote this code but doesn't work correctly.

```
using System;

static void Main()
{
    // Define the time span components
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first duration:");
    Console.Write("Days: ");
    int days1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Hours: ");
    int hours1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Minutes: ");
    int minutes1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the second duration:");
    Console.Write("Days: ");
    int days2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Hours: ");
    int hours2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Minutes: ");
    int minutes2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // Define the duration of each day in your custom time system
    int customMinutesPerDay = 07* 60 + 20;

    // Convert the components to total minutes
    int totalMinutes1 = (days1 * customMinutesPerDay) + (hours1 * 60) + minutes1;
    int totalMinutes2 = (days2 * customMinutesPerDay) + (hours2 * 60) + minutes2;

    // Add the total minutes
    int totalMinutesSum = totalMinutes1 + totalMinutes2;

    // Calculate new days, hours, and minutes
    int newDays = totalMinutesSum / customMinutesPerDay;
    int remainingMinutes = totalMinutesSum % customMinutesPerDay;

    int newHours = remainingMinutes / 60;
    int newMinutes = remainingMinutes % 60;

    Console.WriteLine($"\nTotal Duration: {newDays} days, {newHours} hours, {newMinutes} minutes");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use built in datetime extension in c# ?

Comment: _"I wrote this code but dosnt work correctly"_ - and what is the problem with it?

Comment: What is you start Date?  Do not confuse a DateTime object with a TimeSpan object.  You are adding two TimeSpan objects where a DAY is 24 Hrs.  So you should be getting 19 days, 4 hours, and 80 minutes which is 19 days, 5 hours, 20 minutes.

Comment: What is the expected output and why?

Comment: If i change the  hour instead of 07 for example 08 The output result does not change

Comment: @shingo if you change the hours to 7 hours and 20 minutes or 8 hours and 20 minutes the output does not change

Comment: I know it does not change. My question is what makes you think it should change?

Comment: If my day is 8 hours and 20 minutes instead of 7 hours and 20 minutes, then when I add the days together, the output should be different.

Comment: @user3453159 no it should not (for provided sample inputs). 1 hour 40 minutes + 3 hours 40 minutes still less than a day for both cases i.e. it will not "overflow" to a new day on sum for both cases.

Comment: @GuruStron you mean my code is correct ?

Comment: @user3453159 It seems to me.